# Convert xml to yaml, section "calls"

Tags: symfony, service, yaml

How I can convert this configuration from xml to yaml?

```
<service id="sonata.media.admin.media" class="%sonata.media.admin.media.class%">
...
  <call method="setTemplates">
    <argument type="collection">
      <argument key="list">ApplicationSonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin:list.html.twig</argument>
    </argument>
  </call>
...
</service>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this :

```
services:
  sonata.media.admin.media:
     class: %sonata.media.admin.media.class%
     calls:
            - [setTemplates, [list: "ApplicationSonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin:list.html.twig"]]
```

[Docs here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#optional-dependencies-setter-injection)

Comment: Thank you, but it isn't worked for me.
I have got error with message: 'ErrorException: Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in ... '
I have already found solution by myself.

Comment: @IlyaPoluhin add your solution as an answer or let me know what you did and I will update my answer

Comment: - [setTemplates, [list: "ApplicationSonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin:list.html.twig"]]

Answer (score 2):

[The online converter from Ross Tuck](http://converter.rosstuck.com/) turns out to be a good tool!